# Kinect Depth Histogram in Processing

Tags: processing, kinect, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram displaying the distances scanned by a Kinect vs. their occurrences. I've adapted the Histogram example code to create a depth histogram, but it's currently displaying the depth at each pixel (from left to right) multiple times across the depth image width.
What I'm looking to do is reorder the depth information so that it ranges from the lowest value (that isn't 0) to the highest on the x axis, and shows their occurrences on the y. I'm using Processing, so I'm unsure if this is the right site to be posting on, but I've tried on the posting forum and not gotten any help. If anyone can show me where I'm going wrong, that'd be awesome. My current code is below, and a screenshot of my current output can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14400469/Project%20UI/Histogram.jpg)

```
    import SimpleOpenNI.*;

    SimpleOpenNI kinect;

    void setup() {
      size(1200, 580);

      kinect = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
      kinect.enableDepth();
    }

    void draw () {
      kinect.update();
      PImage depthImage = kinect.depthImage();
      image (depthImage, 11, 0);

      int[] depthValues = kinect.depthMap();
      int[] hist = new int[716800];

      for (int x = 11; x < depthImage.width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < depthImage.height; y++) {
          int i = x + y * 640;
          hist[i] = depthValues[i];
        }
      }

      int histMax = max(hist);

      stroke(20);
      for (int i = 0; i < depthImage.width; i += 2) {
        int which = int(map(i, 0, depthImage.width, 0, histMax));
        int y = int(map(hist[which], 0, histMax, depthImage.height, 0));
        line(i, depthImage.height, i, y);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking two questions here.

**How to get the histogram to go from 0-N:**
Use Processing's [`sort()` function](https://processing.org/reference/sort_.html) to sort the array.

```
hist = sort(hist);  // sorts your array numerically
```

**How to get the histogram to fill the screen:**
I'm not entirely sure why it's drawing twice, but I think you can clean up your code quite a bit.

```
// how far apart are the bars - set based on screen dimensions
int barSpacing = width / hist.length; 

for (int i=0; i<hist.length; i++) {

  // get value and map into usable range (note 10 not 0 for min)
  int h = int(map(hist[i], 0,histMax, 10,height)); 

  // set x position onscreen
  int x = i * barSpacing;

  // draw the bar
  line(x,height, x,height-h);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using the sort function before but didn't get much luck from it. Have just tried your approach and the resultant output is a depth image that shows a frame every few seconds, and a thin line running up the left of the depth image.
I think the issue might be that the histogram data is constantly refreshing due to the Kinect constantly scanning new depth values. Do you have any idea how I'd capture one frame's worth of values?

Thanks for your help